# item post with multiple phone numbers

Tags: php, html, mysql

This request is from a non programmer. An Osclass item post php form code sample is given below.

```
<?php
  $action = 'item_add_post';
  $prepare['s_phone_1'] = del_get_session('sPhone1') <> '' ? del_get_session('sPhone1') : @$item_extra['s_phone_1'];
?>

<div class="input-box">
 <input type="tel" id="sPhone" name="sPhone1[]" value="" />
</div>
<div class="input-box">
 <input type="tel" id="sPhone" name="sPhone1[]" value="" />
</div> 
<div class="input-box">
 <input type="tel" id="sPhone" name="sPhone1[]" value="" />
</div>

<?php
 $prepare = $_POST['sPhone1'];
 ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sPhone1" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($prepare['s_phone_1']));?>">
```

functions.php page has below code also.

```
function del_update_fields($item) {
  if(!isset($item['pk_i_id']) || $item['pk_i_id'] <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if(Params::existParam('sSold')) {
    $fields = array(
      's_phone' => (Params::getParam('contactPhone') <> '' ? Params::getParam('contactPhone') : Params::getParam('sPhone')),
      's_phone_1' => Params::getParam('sPhone1'),
      'i_condition' => Params::getParam('sCondition'),
      'i_negotiable' => Params::getParam('sNegotiable'),
      'i_transaction' => Params::getParam('sTransaction'),
      'i_sold' => (Params::getParam('sSold') == 'on' ? 1 : Params::getParam('sSold'))
    );
  } else {
    $fields = array(
      's_phone' => (Params::getParam('contactPhone') <> '' ? Params::getParam('contactPhone') : Params::getParam('sPhone')),
      's_phone_1' => Params::getParam('sPhone1'),
      'i_condition' => Params::getParam('sCondition'),
      'i_negotiable' => Params::getParam('sNegotiable'),
      'i_transaction' => Params::getParam('sTransaction')
    );
  }

  Item::newInstance()->dao->update(DB_TABLE_PREFIX.'t_item_delta', $fields, array('fk_i_item_id' => $item['pk_i_id']));
}
```

[Screenshot of the db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPO7f.png)

Requirement is to store phone numbers in above 3 name="sPhone1[]" inputs in "s_phone_1" as below example.
**0091222222222;0091333333333;0091666666666;**

But it stores N; in mysql. Need your help to correct above code to pass these numbers as an array. And later, need to get them back in to 3 lines as below in another page.

Phone 1: 0091222222222
Phone 2: 0091333333333
Phone 3: 0091666666666

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where is the code you use to store the phone numbers in the database?

Comment: I added a code from functions.php page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting values in the array and now these array values you want in "**s_phone_1**"

use this code to get value in "s_phone_1"
here you can store $phonenumbers in your database

```
$phonenumbers =  implode(";",$_POST['sPhone1']);
//echo $phonenumbers;
```

output

```
09874563214;09874563214;09874563214
```

now for getting value as per your requirement

get value from the database and store it in $phonenumbers

```
$getPhoneNumbers = explode(";",$phonenumbers);
echo "Phone 1:" .$getPhoneNumbers[0]."<br>";
echo "Phone 2:" .$getPhoneNumbers[1]."<br>";
echo "Phone 3:" .$getPhoneNumbers[2]."<br>";
```

output

```
Phone 1:09874563214
Phone 2:09874563214
Phone 3:09874563214
```

Comment: Can you please advice where should I place implode(";",$_POST['sPhone1']); in functions.php given above because I'm getting a syntax error when I put it in form area.

Comment: You can use this code below the $prepare = $_POST['sPhone1']; and for reference open this link. https://prnt.sc/CJAkx6HmHaAs

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.. I had to set the $phonenumbers =  implode(";",$_POST['sPhone1']); part in functions.php according to my setup. My bad of understanding took a time to resolve it.. :) Thank you so much..!